# KUSTO QUERY LANGUAGE (KQL) - Cannot unpack the dictionary

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

I have a table wherein i uploaded the file with a column converted to json. but when im tryin to upack it using KQL. it does not work.

```
Id  Query Name  Workitem Id Logged Date Details
0   Bug Stats   111 2022-06-08T02:26:43.111196Z {'AssignedTo': 'me', 'ClosedDate': None, 'CreatedDate': '2022-03-08T19:28:15.673Z', 'StartDate': None, 'State': 'For Review', 'Tags': 'tags', 'Title': 'Title', 'WorkItemType': 'Bug'}
```

Returns nothing

```
Datatable
|extend  Details = parse_json(Details) //i tried todynamic() as well but same response
|evaluate bag_unpack(Details)
```

Returns Error:

```html
Datatable
|evaluate bag_unpack(Details)
```

ERROR:
Semantic error: evaluate bag_unpack(): the following error(s) occurred while evaluating the output schema: evaluate bag_unpack(): argument #1 expected to be a reference to a dynamic column. Query: 'DevopsQueriesTest |evaluate bag_unpack(Details) '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you do need to first invoke `parse_json()` on `Details`, for creating a `dynamic` value out of a `string` value.

   see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction
2. the input string you have isn't a valid JSON payload - it uses single quotes instead of double quotes.

   - it's best that you fix the component that generates the data, and ingest valid payloads instead of invalid ones.
   - if, for whatever reason, you can't/won't do so - and you prefer paying a performance hit as part of your queries, you can use the `translate()` function, for example.

     - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/translatefunction
   - Moreover, the `None` in your payload is invalid too - it needs to be encapsulated with double quotes for the JSON payload to become valid.

     - you can use the `replace_string()` function to fix that at query runtime.
     - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/replace-string-function

```
print s = "{'AssignedTo': 'me', 'ClosedDate': None, 'CreatedDate': '2022-03-08T19:28:15.673Z', 'StartDate': None, 'State': 'For Review', 'Tags': 'tags', 'Title': 'Title', 'WorkItemType': 'Bug'}"
| project s = parse_json(replace_string(translate("'", '"', s), "None", '"None"'))
| evaluate bag_unpack(s)
```

| AssignedTo | ClosedDate | CreatedDate | StartDate | State | Tags | Title | WorkItemType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| me | None | 2022-03-08 19:28:15.6730000 | None | For Review | tags | Title | Bug |